# C# XmlNode.ChildNodes breakline count as node

Tags: c#

I have these xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/">
    <atom:id>urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000</atom:id>
    <atom:title>RenamedDocument</atom:title>
    <atom:updated>2012-07-13T06:14:05Z</atom:updated>
    <cmisra:object xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
        <cmis:properties>
        <cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name">
                <cmis:value>RenamedDocument</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmisma:[OSTERONE]Test">
                <cmis:value>[NULL]</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
        </cmis:properties>
    </cmisra:object>
</atom:entry>
```

and I would like to have every children of `cmis:property` so I do

`XmlNodeList list = rawData.GetElementsByTagName("cmis:properties")[0].ChildNodes;`
but I have 5 children. It's appear that every \n is count as a node.

How can I suppress these breakline to have only the "real children" ?

Comment: I'd recommend switching from the old `System.Xml` DOM to the new `System.Linq.Xml` where you have methods that will return elements.  If you stick with the old DOM you'll have to filter on the `NodeType`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unfortunaly stuck with framework 4.0 and no highter 
I will test with `NodeType` ty

Comment: The new DOM was added in c# 3.0, so it's not really new.  You're just using the really old one.

Comment: Ok, I will check Linq, but filter on `NodeType` worked, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to juharr, I found a way with `NodeType`.
Just have to make an if condition with `NodeType != NodeType.Whitespace`.
Thanks you !